# A signalling thread problem

Tags: linux, multithreading, boost, signals

I am attempting to get a thread running which will be responsible for detecting a signal from any other thread within the same process.

```
sigset_t    sigset;
sigfillset(&sigset);
pthread_sigmask( SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, &old );
```

Once i've done this, I then daemonize the process:

```
m_child = fork();
if (m_child == 0)
{
     // Start the thread responsible for detecting a signal
}
```

This is done within another class called "SignalHandler" where the kick-off to this thread is done as follows:

```
m_pThread   = new boost::thread( boost::bind(&SignalHandler::operator(), this ) );
```

and the functor operates in a tight loop as follows:

```
while (1)
{
    if ( sigtimedwait( &sigset, &info, &ts ) == -1 )
    {
        if ( errno == EAGAIN || errno == EINTR )
        {
            std::cout << "Time-out waiting for signal" << std::endl;
        }

        throw SystemError( "sigtimedwait error" );
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Detected a signal [" << info.si_signo << "]" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This works when I do a "kill -9 myProcess", but when I actually perform some illegal pointer manipulation (in any other thread), the process core dumps.

Why is the signal produced by the child thread not caught in my boost signal-catching thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah - I got it.

The problem is here:

```
sigset_t    sigset;
sigfillset(&sigset);
pthread_sigmask( SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, &old );
```

Using sigfillset for pthread_sigmask is dangerous because blocking the synchronous signals causes undesirable effects.

> If any of the SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGSEGV,
>   or SIGBUS signals are generated while
>   they are blocked, the result is
>   undefined, unless the signal was
>   generated by the kill() function, the
>   sigqueue() function, or the raise()
>   function.